I need to set active button when it is clicked. I am using bootstrap
Even though I tried every method it does not seem to override. I tried a lot of different methods like fiddling with CSS but nothing seems to work. I am using bootstrap 5


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const notesButton = document.getElementById('notes');
  const tasksButton = document.getElementById('tasks');

  notesButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    notesButton.classList.add('active');
    tasksButton.classList.remove('active');
  });

  tasksButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    tasksButton.classList.add('active');
    notesButton.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
  <title>Trackz</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <nav class="navbar tabar mx-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-4 text_color" href="/">
                Trackz
            </a>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <a href="/"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="notes">Notes</button></a>
          <a href="/Tasks"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="tasks">Tasks</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>




Why are you nesting buttons inside an anchor?

HTML does not allow nesting of button into a, or vice versa, since they are both considered "interactive" elements. If you want to link somewhere, use a link. If you want that link to look like a button - apply CSS to format it accordingly.

Why you even need to apply something if you navigate away from page after clicking link?

Since your buttons are wrapped in anchor tags that navigate to different pages (href="/" and href="/Tasks"), clicking them will naturally cause the browser to navigate away, thus not preserving the active state visually on the buttons.
You can use preventDefault(), but it does not make sense since you can rather not use the anchor tags at all.
I would highly recommend to brainstorm the behaviour you want to achieve and based on that change your HTML structure.
Anyway here is a snippet that adds the feature you are after with preventDefault()


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const notesButton = document.getElementById('notes');
  const tasksButton = document.getElementById('tasks');

  notesButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the page navigation
    notesButton.classList.add('active');
    tasksButton.classList.remove('active');
  });

  tasksButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the page navigation
    tasksButton.classList.add('active');
    notesButton.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
  <title>Trackz</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <nav class="navbar tabar mx-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-4 text_color" href="/">
                Trackz
            </a>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <a href="/"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="notes">Notes</button></a>
          <a href="/Tasks"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="tasks">Tasks</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>




You're not using preventDefault on the anchor but on the button so it's still redirecting.

You are using anchor tags navigate to different pages. So you have to use preventDefault() on the event listener. Check Example below:


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const notesButton = document.getElementById('notes');
  const tasksButton = document.getElementById('tasks');

  notesButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    notesButton.classList.add('active');
    tasksButton.classList.remove('active');
  });

  tasksButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tasksButton.classList.add('active');
    notesButton.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
  <title>Trackz</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <nav class="navbar tabar mx-5">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand mx-4 text_color" href="/">
                Trackz
            </a>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <a href="/"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="notes">Notes</button></a>
          <a href="/Tasks"><button class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" id="tasks">Tasks</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>



